# Delete same name but similar address in csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

So I have csv with data like this:

```
Restaurant         Rating             Address
Birdman              5                18 Parc SCBD, Tower B, Lantai Ground, Jl. Jenderal Sudirman Kav 52 - 53
Bistecca             4                18 Parc SCBD, Tower C, Lantai Ground, Jl. Jenderal Sudirman Kav 52-53, SCBD, Jakarta
Lake View            5                The Spring Club, Jl. Springs Boulevard Blok C No. 1
Lake View Cafe       4.5              The Springs Club, Jl. Springs Boulevard Blok C No. 1
Henshin              4.2              The Westin Jakarta, Lantai 67 - 69, Jl. HR Rasuna Said Kavling C No. 22A
Henshin              4.4              The Westin Jakarta, Lantai 67-69, Jl. H. R. Rasuna Said, Kuningan, Jakarta 12940
Hua Shen             4.3              THR Lokasari, Jl. Mangga Besar Raya
KFC                  4.3              THR Lokasari, Jl. Mangga Besar Raya
```

That was some example of 26k restaurant list including their attribute like rating, address, etc from scraping two different websites. Merge them into one csv so can fill each other lack of restaurant name data. What I need is to get rid a rows with same name and same address. But as you can see there is a some data with same name but similar address, even like the first 'Henshin' is with block and number and the second one without it but had a region and postal code.

And there is different restaurant name but same address. Of course there is a row  with the same name and address on my csv. But the difficult one for me is rows like above. Is there any way to delete a rows with same name but similar address? Either from Excel or Python.

Answer (score 0):

Using similarity score for address can solve this issue. One of the library in python for this is SequenceMatcher from difflib.
You have to do hit and trial for getting thresold score to filter.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
score = similar(address1 , address2)
```

[image]